# How can I have a parent and child processes modify and read the same variable?

Tags: c, concurrency, parent-child, child-process

I have to do a project in C using child processes and pipe communication , but I cannot get it to work properly.

The project consists on a menu of operations to do in a linked list, we can load a new node to the list, delete one node, print the info of one node, print the info of all nodes etc...

```
void menu(){
  printf("Introduzca una de las siguientes opciones: \n\n");
  printf("1. load \n");
  printf("2. delete \n");
  printf("3. info \n");
  printf("4. infoall \n");
  printf("5. help \n");
  printf("6. save_collection \n");
  printf("7. load_collection \n");
  printf("8. add_op_id \n");
  printf("0. exit \n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("Si introduce CTRL+D en este menÃº, el programa terminarÃ¡ de forma controlada.\n");
  printf("\n");

}
```

What I need to achieve is that whenever I load a new node into the list I create a child process which is the one who will execute the operations on the node, the parent process will only recieve the option and communicate it to the child process through a pipe so the child can read and call that function/option.

My problem is that, I call fork() in case: load is called, and then if the child is created fine I load the node into the list, however this list is a "copy" of the list of the parent process so if I load another node it will be loaded into a new copy of the list of the parent, and overall if the parent wants to print for example the information of the nodes of its list it will appear empty as the list on which we have loaded the nodes is not the "original" one.

I add the code of the main program (the code is downgraded to try at first with one basic operation):

```
int main(int argc, char *arg_argv[]) 
{


  int error=0;
  signal_inicio();
  menu();
  int fd[2];

  if(pipe(fd)){
    perror("pipe(...)");
    exit(1);
  }
  char opcion[]= "infoall";
  //opcion[strlen(opcion)+1]='\0';
  int salir = 1;  



  while(salir==1){
    printf("\n");
    printf("Introduzca una opción válida: %d", getpid());
    long option = get_number(&error);
    if(error != 0){
      libero();
      printf("ERROR: Opción no válida\n");
    }

    switch(option){

    case 0:
      puts("---Ha seleccionado exit---");
      puts("---TERMINAMOS---");
      printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());
      vaciarLista(&lista);
      libero();
      salir = 0;
      //exit(0);

      break;

    case 1:
      //int status;
      puts("---Ha seleccionado load---");
      printf("\n Introduzca un nombre de archivo\n");
      char *archivo = get_string(&error);
      if(error!=0){
    libero();
    printf("Introduzca un nombre de archivo valido.\n");

      }else{

    pid_t pid; 
    pid = fork();

    if (pid==-1){
      //No se ha creado bien el hijo
      perror("fork()");
      //exit(1);

    }else if(pid == 0){
      //El hijo se ha creado bien, creo la pipe fd
      //Cargo el archivo con el pid y los descriptores de fichero.
      load(&lista, archivo, getpid(), fd ,&error);
      printf("El f[0] del PADRE es: %d: \n", fd[0]);
      child(&lista);

      break;
    }else{

      printf("Soy el padre y escribo en el pipe: %d %s\n", getpid(),opcion);

    }   
      }
      break;

    case 2:
     puts("---Ha seleccionado delete---");
      printf("\n Introduzca el identificador del nodo que quiere borrar: \n");
      long option3 = get_number(&error);
      if(error!=0){
    libero();
    printf("Oh oh, an error happened!\n");
      }
      printf("The second number is: %ld\n",option3);
      delete(&lista, option3, &error);

      wait(NULL);
      break;

    case 3:
      puts("---Ha seleccionado info---");

    break;

    case 4:

      puts("---Ha seleccionado infoall---");
      write(fd[1],opcion,(strlen(opcion)+1));
      printf("PADRE\n");
      infolista_all(&lista);
      //close(fd[1]);

      break;

    case 5:
      puts("---Ha seleccionado help---");
      menu();
      break;

    default:
      break;
    } 
  }
  vaciarLista(&lista);
  libero();
  return 0;
}
```

Child function:

```
void child(struct lista *lista){
  char buff[50];
  printf("--1--\n");
  printf("El fd[0] del HIJO es: %d: \n", lista->head->fd[0]);
  while(1){

    printf("--2--\n");
    int nbytes = read(lista->head->fd[0],buff, sizeof(buff));

    printf("--3--\n");
    if(nbytes>0){

      printf("--4--\n");
      printf("Bytes: %d \n", nbytes);
      printf("Recibido: %s \n",buff);
      /* if(strcmp(buff,"infoall")==0){
      infolista_all(lista);
    }else{

    }*/

      //break;
    }else{
      printf("No hemos leido nada \n");
    }

    break;
    //exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the source to load(), but if it is merely a book-keeping sort of thing:

```
load(&lista, archivo, 0, fd ,&error);

pid = fork();

if (pid==-1){
  //No se ha creado bien el hijo
  perror("fork()");
  //exit(1);

}else if(pid == 0){
  list.pid = getpid();
  //El hijo se ha creado bien, creo la pipe fd
  //Cargo el archivo con el pid y los descriptores de fichero.
  printf("El f[0] del PADRE es: %d: \n", fd[0]);
  child(&lista);

  break;
```

That is, move the generic construction of the data object up into the parent; and edit the child-specific parts in the child.   Each has their own copy, so won't really interfere with each other.